# quarter results or quarter's result?

Tags: possessives

I'd like to know whether the possessive 's is needed in the following:

The manager is satisfied with **the quarter's** results.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It may be worth noting that Google Books claims just 2 instances of [with the quarter's results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+the+quarter%27s+results%22) and 3 of [with the quarter results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+the+quarter+results%22) (none of which can be read in context). Compare that to an estimated 494 hits for [with the **quarterly** results.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+the+quarterly+results%22)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the possessive is needed.

"The manager is satisfied with the quarter results" means that the results are only one fourth of what were possible. "Quarter" is modifying "results".

What was intended by your sentence was "The manager was pleased by the results of the quarter," where "quarter" means some specific but implicit quarter of a specific but implicit year. We could mean the same thing by using the adjective "quarterly" as in "The manager was pleased by the quarterly results." Or we could replace the phrase "of the quarter" by a possessive construction as in "The manager was satisfied by the quarter's results."

Comment: I agree, but a related use, "The manager is satisfied with the first-quarter results" does not use the possessive.

Comment: Yes, people do write that kind of hyphenated adjective, but I cannot remember **hearing** it during a long financial career. I think it is a usage used primarily by the financial press and PR types. Of course I may be hearing what I expect, not what was actually enunciated. But I think saying "Here are the year results" or "Here are the month results" is just weird so I'd never say "Here are the quarter results."